# Package caption error: left undefined

Tags: errors, captions

So I'm in a bit of a rut here, have been working on this file in collaboration with a senior member of my faculty, and the file I have received from him after revisions, posts this error that I have absolutely no explanation for.

So, all other captions, everywhere in the file are working alright, but there's this one at `line:292`, which doesn't seem to work. Whenever I attempt to compile, the console flashes the error `'Package caption error: left undefined'`. The code is something like this.

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=12.5cm]{condweights.pdf}
\caption{Time-varying utility maximizing portfolio weights for risk aversion parameter $c=5$ (and $b=0$). In each period, the sum of the weights is 1. The weights are restricted to the interval $[-0.25,1.25]$.\label{condweights}}
\end{figure}
```

What's even more upsetting is that even if I remove the entire segment (to the point that there isn't even a `line:292` anymore!), the console still flashes the same error on the very same line. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

PS: I'm using TexMaker 4.5, btw.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The error message you report indicates that one or more options passed to the `caption` package weren't set correctly. Please do tell us how the `caption` package is loaded. If you have a `\captionsetup` instruction, do let us know what its argument is.

Comment: Hi @Mico, that would be `\usepackage[justification=left,font=footnotesize,width=10cm]{caption}`. I do not see a problem there. But please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `left` is not a standard option for `justification` in `caption`.  Do you mean `raggedleft` or have you defined your own justification style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`left`" is not a predefined option for the `justification` key.

According to the user guide of the `caption` package, the predefined options are `justified`, `centering`, `centerlast`, `centerfirst`, `raggedright`, `raggedleft` as well as (assuming the `ragged2e` package is loaded) `Centering`, `RaggedRight`, and `RaggedLeft`.

In addition, custom justification methods may be defined using a `\DeclareCaptionJustification` declaration. See p. 25 of the package's user guide for more information on this subject.

I have a hunch that what you want is `justification=raggedright`.